# ClassRegistry::init not picking up datetime format from within datasource

Tags: php, cakephp, datasource

```
<?php
class PluginModel extends PluginAppModel {
  public function hello(){
    $anotherModel =& ClassRegistry::init('Plugin.PluginAnotherModel');

    $this->read();

    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);
    $db->begin($this);

    $anotherModel->create(array('AnotherModel' => $this->data['PluginModel']));
    $anotherModel->save();

    $db->commit($this);
  }
}
?>
```

This script is calling another model using the ClassRegistry::init() function. Grabbing the data from the current model and putting it into the create() on the other model initiated.
When it tries to save I get a SqlServer error converting char to datetime.
When I debug the data it shows the INSERT datetime format as 'Y-m-d' but in my app/model/datasource/Sqlserver.php I have specified datetime = 'Ymd'.

Why is the datetime format not being picked up? It works as expected on a normal model save, but not when I call another model in with the ClassRegistry::init function?

I have a work around of looping through the dataset before save to convert any datetime fields into the 'Ymd', but this does not sound like the right way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Sorry this is version 2

Comment: You could probably reduce your whole method to 2 lines.. Why all the overhead?

Comment: I have cut out a load of other bits of code atm just to get this bit working. Any ideas why it is behaving like this??

Comment: First of all don't use read(). Use find(). Then, regarding your issue, this might as well be a bug in the SqlServer datasource. Can you reproduce it with a clean controller/model? You could then file a bug report.

Comment: I can reproduce it within the plugin, but within the main app it works. I have debugged into which datasource the plugin is using, and it is looking at the right one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just converted the date formats in php in the end as was running out of time.